# What is the way to delete words in Python list which does not have numbers?

Tags: python, regex

```
 a = ['in 1978 by', 'History', 'members', 'albums', 'June 4th, 1979', 'October 7,1986): "The Lounge', 'In 1984 the', 'early 1990s; prominent']
```

the above list have words like history, members which do not have numbers in them, so i want to delete them

```
 # output would be
 a = ['in 1978 by', 'June 4th, 1979', 'October 7, 1986', 'In 1984 the', 'early 1990s; prominent']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep the ones you want:

```
a = ['in 1978 by', 'History', 'members', 'albums', 'June 4th, 1979', 'October 7,1986): "The Lounge', 'In 1984 the', 'early 1990s; prominent']

new = [el for el in a if any(ch.isdigit() for ch in el)]
# ['in 1978 by', 'June 4th, 1979', 'October 7,1986): "The Lounge', 'In 1984 the', 'early 1990s; prominent']
```

Comment: +1 for list comprehension.@jon: can you briefly tell how the if any(ch.isdigit()) works? especially what the 'any" do..Thanks

Comment: @user1988876 we take each element from the list. Then take each character from that and check to see if any of them are a digit - if so, we can deduce it's true and add it to our output list. This means the check can short circuit as soon as it finds a number. (So - for the first one - we only need to get to the `1` in `1948` to determine we want to include it....)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter alternative, using `any()` and `string.digits`:

```
from string import digits

a = ['in 1978 by', 'History', 'members', 'albums', 'June 4th, 1979', 
     'October 7,1986): "The Lounge', 'In 1984 the', 'early 1990s; prominent']

[x for x in a if any(y in x for y in digits)]

=> ['in 1978 by', 'June 4th, 1979', 'October 7,1986): "The Lounge',
    'In 1984 the', 'early 1990s; prominent']
```

Comment: The inversion of the search (compared to the accepted answer) from "are any of these characters digits" to "are any digits in this string" probably gives better performance in python.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression and a list comprehension, this is a one-liner:

```
import re
[i for i in a if re.search('\d', i) is not None]
```

Comment: There's no generator here. (Also, it's a one-liner without regular expressions too.)

Comment: Fixed. That's great that it's a one-liner through other means also.